# How to position a div left to another div and top fixed to body?

Tags: css, css-position

I would like to add a menu left to a div but fixed relative to the top of the body. So when I scroll the div, the left menu sticks to the screen.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 1300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.menu_fixed_left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: silver;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu_fixed_left">
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    Container
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vincentr/mkksLwvz/).

Comment: [`.menu_fixed_left { position: fixed; }`](https://jsfiddle.net/x7k8L7ky/)?

Comment: -> insertusernamehere : with position:fixed, the left menu doesn't stick to the main div left border when the width of the screen is modified.

Comment: You can simply calculate the value for `left` using percentages, like suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37611910/1456376).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to follow some steps:

- First of all, you will have to display your menu as `fixed`.
- Second, to position it on the top of the `body`, you will have to use `top: 0` (or you can change it to your desired top taking as reference the body tag).
- As the content div occupy the 70% of the width of the screen with `margin: auto` it means that it has 15% (30% that is not occupy and the same at each side, 30%/2 = 15%) of the screen on each side so you will have to use calc to rest to the 15% of each side, the 50px that occupy your menu.
- Remove the default margin of your `body` tag.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkksLwvz/3/).

Comment: I think he doesn't wan't it to be stuck on top (top: 0)

Comment: @Juanín What I can understand from the question is that he wants it on the top of the body but I will wait until he tell something. Anyway, I let him know that he can change the value for its desired top taking as reference the body tag).

Comment: I'll use a margin-top:100px; I like you answer because of the use of : left: calc(15% - 50px);

Comment: @Vincent Be aware that using  `margin-top: 100px` you are occupying a space and with `top: 100px` you will not.

Comment: @Error404 Sorry, As it is my first post, I misused the button. It works great !

Comment: Is it ok if I correct the original fiddle. Or is it better to post a new one with correction ? or just doing nothing ? (sorry this is my first post)

Comment: @Vincent No, you should not correct the original fiddle because in this way people can see what was the error and how to fix it. It is a bit hard at the beginning start in this community but you will see that it is awesome. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu_fixed_left {
position: fixed;
left:194px;
width: 50px;
margin-top: 100px;
z-index: 2;
background-color: silver;
}
```

Instead of `position: absolute;` have `position: fixed;` and change left property to 200px
[Pen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/aZOmjJ)

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS to

```
.menu_fixed_left{
  position: fixed; /* fixed position */
  left: 15%; /* left side of .container */
  margin-left: -50px; /* set it to the left, the same amount as the width*/
  background-color:silver;
  width:50px;
  margin-top:100px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

CSS is commented to explain what it does.

[**Updated FIddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mkksLwvz/5/)

Answer (score 0):

`Position:fixed` should do **if you use margin instead coordonates**:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkksLwvz/6/

*Test snippet below in full page and resize window to find out*

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 1300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.menu_fixed_left {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -50px;/* instead left */
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: silver;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu_fixed_left">
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    Container
  </div>
</body>
```